# A strange answer for $\int _{-1}^1 \log x\; dx$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, wolfram-alpha

I typed $\int _{-1}^1 \log x\; dx$ on Wolfram Alpha. It is giving the answer to be $-2+i\pi$. Can someone please explain what is happening?

Comment: What do you know about the complex logarithm?

Comment: $$\int\ln x\ dx=x\ln x-x+C$$

Comment: @fixedp I know that the logarithm has a singularity at 0 and also that we require branch to make it analytic but I do not understand how that is related to the question

Comment: @Tunk-Fey what happens at 0?

Comment: To add to Tunk Fey's comment: $e^{i\pi} = -1$, so $\ln(-1) = i\pi$ (for an appropriate branch of $\ln$.

Comment: @JimmyK4542 thank you but what happens at 0?

Comment: @happymath L'Hospital, if you care about what happen at $x=0$.

Comment: @happymath $\log x$ is not defined at $x = 0$ but it's an isolated point. $\log x$ is continuous otherwise so $\int \log x dx$ for $x\in [-1,1]$ would be the same as $\int \log x dx$ for $x\in [-1,0)\cup(0,1]$

Comment: What happens to $x \log(x)$ when $x$ goes to $0$ ?

Comment: @Tunk Fey thanks a lot so you mean that $x lnx \rightarrow 0 as x\rightarrow 0$ but what happens if we choose some other path in the complex plane?

Comment: The given expression  is **undefined** as it stands.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

WA is probably summing the well-defined integrals $$\int_0^1\log x\,\mathrm dx=\left.x\log x-x\right|_0^1=-1$$ and $$\int_{-1}^0\log x\,\mathrm dx,$$ using the *convention* that, when $x$ is real and negative, $\log x=\mathrm i\pi+\log|x|$, hence  $$\int_{-1}^0\log x\,\mathrm dx=\int_0^1(\mathrm i\pi+\log u)\,\mathrm du=\mathrm i\pi-1,$$ by the first computation.

The validity of such a move could be questioned since an equally valid definition of the (complex) logarithm on the negative real axis would be that $\log x=-\mathrm i\pi+\log|x|$ for every $x\lt0$, or that $\log x=43\mathrm i\pi+\log|x|$ for every $x\lt0$, or that...

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil\, #1 \,\right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
With the $\ds{\ln}$-branch cut:
$$
\ln\pars{z}=\ln\pars{\verts{z}} + {\rm Arg}\pars{z}\ic\,,\quad
-\,{\pi \over 2} < {\rm Arg}\pars{z} < {3\pi \over 2}\,,\quad z \not= 0 
$$

> \begin{align}&\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\braces{%
> \int_{-1}^{-\epsilon}\bracks{\ln\pars{-x} + \pi\,\ic}\,\dd x
> +\int_{\pi}^{0}
> \ln\pars{\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}}\,\epsilon\expo{\ic\theta}\ic\dd\theta
> +\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}
> \\[3mm]&=\lim_{\epsilon\ \to\ 0^{+}}\braces{%
> \int_{\epsilon}^{1}\bracks{\ln\pars{x} + \pi\ic}\,\dd x
> +\int_{\epsilon}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}
> =2\ \overbrace{\int_{0}^{1}\ln\pars{x}\,\dd x}
> ^{\ds{\color{#c00000}{\large=\ -1}}}\ +\ \pi\ic
> \\[3mm]&=\color{#66f}{\Large -2 + \pi\ic}
> \end{align}